# Intercept print data of DOS based printing

Tags: printing, dos, redmon

I have successfully used Redmon to intercept print data when the printing software uses windows based printing.

But currently the software that I am trying to use [Redmon](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/redmon/info) with, is sending the print
data using DOS print architecture, which Redmon is not able to intercept.

So I wanted to know if there is some configuration in Redmon, or if there
is some other tool available which can work with Redmon to intercept the
DOS Print data.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to do a similar thing, redirect dos print to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Dos program with Windows 64 bit and print, try:
http://schaars.nl/vDos.7z